# swapping char VHDL FPGA

Tags: fpga, vhdl

I want to develop an application that is able to get and store 
two input values, swap from lower case to upper case only the first 
value and finally output the two stored values. E.g.: if the input 
string is "john", then the output string should be "JoHn". The 
application should get "j" from user_w_write_8_data and store it into 
`my_buffer_a`, swap "j" into "J", then get "o" store it into `my_buffer_b`, 
then output "J", then output "o". After that the application should get 
"h" from `user_w_write_8_data`,  swap "h" into "H", and store it into 
`my_buffer_a`, then get "n" store it into `my_buffer_b`, then output "H", 
then output "n". Basically, the application should store two characters, 
swap the first one and then output these two, store other two 
characters, swap the first one and then output these two characters etc. 
The problem of my application does not swap lower to upper characters 
that is stored into `my_buffer_a`. Instead of outputing "JoHn", my 
application outputs blank line and input random char.
My app is based on this code [link](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/205809/storing-values-on-variable-fpga-vhdl?noredirect=1#) but I opened a new topic because this logic is quite different! 
As suggested, I control signals like `wr_en` , `din` and `full` of the XillyBus as well. One more thing, unfortunately I cannot run the simulation but only generate the bitfile and test it right away on my FPGA.

Thanks.

Here the code:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity xillydemo is
  port (
PCIE_PERST_B_LS : IN std_logic;
PCIE_REFCLK_N : IN std_logic;
PCIE_REFCLK_P : IN std_logic;
PCIE_RX_N : IN std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);
PCIE_RX_P : IN std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);
GPIO_LED : OUT std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);
PCIE_TX_N : OUT std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);
PCIE_TX_P : OUT std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0));
end xillydemo;

architecture sample_arch of xillydemo is
  component xillybus
    port (
  PCIE_PERST_B_LS : IN std_logic;
  PCIE_REFCLK_N : IN std_logic;
  PCIE_REFCLK_P : IN std_logic;
  PCIE_RX_N : IN std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);
  PCIE_RX_P : IN std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);
  GPIO_LED : OUT std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);
  PCIE_TX_N : OUT std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);
  PCIE_TX_P : OUT std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);
  bus_clk : OUT std_logic;
  quiesce : OUT std_logic;
  user_r_mem_8_rden : OUT std_logic;
  user_r_mem_8_empty : IN std_logic;
  user_r_mem_8_data : IN std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);
  user_r_mem_8_eof : IN std_logic;
  user_r_mem_8_open : OUT std_logic;
  user_w_mem_8_wren : OUT std_logic;
  user_w_mem_8_full : IN std_logic;
  user_w_mem_8_data : OUT std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);
  user_w_mem_8_open : OUT std_logic;
  user_mem_8_addr : OUT std_logic_vector(4 DOWNTO 0);
  user_mem_8_addr_update : OUT std_logic;
  user_r_read_32_rden : OUT std_logic;
  user_r_read_32_empty : IN std_logic;
  user_r_read_32_data : IN std_logic_vector(31 DOWNTO 0);
  user_r_read_32_eof : IN std_logic;
  user_r_read_32_open : OUT std_logic;
  user_r_read_8_rden : OUT std_logic;
  user_r_read_8_empty : IN std_logic;
  user_r_read_8_data : IN std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);
  user_r_read_8_eof : IN std_logic;
  user_r_read_8_open : OUT std_logic;
  user_w_write_32_wren : OUT std_logic;
  user_w_write_32_full : IN std_logic;
  user_w_write_32_data : OUT std_logic_vector(31 DOWNTO 0);
  user_w_write_32_open : OUT std_logic;
  user_w_write_8_wren : OUT std_logic;
  user_w_write_8_full : IN std_logic;
  user_w_write_8_data : OUT std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);
  user_w_write_8_open : OUT std_logic);
  end component;

  component fifo_8x2048
    port (
  clk: IN std_logic;
  srst: IN std_logic;
  din: IN std_logic_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
  wr_en: IN std_logic;
  rd_en: IN std_logic;
  dout: OUT std_logic_VECTOR(7 downto 0);
  full: OUT std_logic;
  empty: OUT std_logic);
  end component;

  component fifo_32x512
    port (
  clk: IN std_logic;
  srst: IN std_logic;
  din: IN std_logic_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
  wr_en: IN std_logic;
  rd_en: IN std_logic;
  dout: OUT std_logic_VECTOR(31 downto 0);
  full: OUT std_logic;
  empty: OUT std_logic);
  end component;

-- Synplicity black box declaration
  attribute syn_black_box : boolean;
  attribute syn_black_box of fifo_32x512: component is true;
  attribute syn_black_box of fifo_8x2048: component is true;

  type demo_mem is array(0 TO 31) of std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);
  signal demoarray : demo_mem;

  signal bus_clk :  std_logic;
  signal quiesce : std_logic;

  signal reset_8 : std_logic;
  signal reset_32 : std_logic;

  signal ram_addr : integer range 0 to 31;

  signal user_r_mem_8_rden :  std_logic;
  signal user_r_mem_8_empty :  std_logic;
  signal user_r_mem_8_data :  std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);
  signal user_r_mem_8_eof :  std_logic;
  signal user_r_mem_8_open :  std_logic;
  signal user_w_mem_8_wren :  std_logic;
  signal user_w_mem_8_full :  std_logic;
  signal user_w_mem_8_data :  std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);
  signal user_w_mem_8_open :  std_logic;
  signal user_mem_8_addr :  std_logic_vector(4 DOWNTO 0);
  signal user_mem_8_addr_update :  std_logic;
  signal user_r_read_32_rden :  std_logic;
  signal user_r_read_32_empty :  std_logic;
  signal user_r_read_32_data :  std_logic_vector(31 DOWNTO 0);
  signal user_r_read_32_eof :  std_logic;
  signal user_r_read_32_open :  std_logic;
  signal user_r_read_8_rden :  std_logic;
  signal user_r_read_8_empty :  std_logic;
  signal user_r_read_8_data :  std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);
  signal user_r_read_8_eof :  std_logic;
  signal user_r_read_8_open :  std_logic;
  signal user_w_write_32_wren :  std_logic;
  signal user_w_write_32_full :  std_logic;
  signal user_w_write_32_data :  std_logic_vector(31 DOWNTO 0);
  signal user_w_write_32_open :  std_logic;
  signal user_w_write_8_wren :  std_logic;
  signal user_w_write_8_full :  std_logic;
  signal user_w_write_8_data :  std_logic_vector(7 DOWNTO 0);
  signal user_w_write_8_open :  std_logic;

  signal wr_en               :  std_logic := '0';
  signal rd_en               :  std_logic := '0';
  signal full                :  std_logic := '0';
  signal empty               :  std_logic := '0';

  signal my_buffer_a :  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
  signal my_buffer_b :  std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) := (others => '0');
  signal counter : integer := 0;



begin
  xillybus_ins : xillybus
port map (
  -- Ports related to /dev/xillybus_mem_8
  -- FPGA to CPU signals:
  user_r_mem_8_rden => user_r_mem_8_rden,
  user_r_mem_8_empty => user_r_mem_8_empty,
  user_r_mem_8_data => user_r_mem_8_data,
  user_r_mem_8_eof => user_r_mem_8_eof,
  user_r_mem_8_open => user_r_mem_8_open,
  -- CPU to FPGA signals:
  user_w_mem_8_wren => user_w_mem_8_wren,
  user_w_mem_8_full => user_w_mem_8_full,
  user_w_mem_8_data => user_w_mem_8_data,
  user_w_mem_8_open => user_w_mem_8_open,
  -- Address signals:
  user_mem_8_addr => user_mem_8_addr,
  user_mem_8_addr_update => user_mem_8_addr_update,

  -- Ports related to /dev/xillybus_read_32
  -- FPGA to CPU signals:
  user_r_read_32_rden => user_r_read_32_rden,
  user_r_read_32_empty => user_r_read_32_empty,
  user_r_read_32_data => user_r_read_32_data,
  user_r_read_32_eof => user_r_read_32_eof,
  user_r_read_32_open => user_r_read_32_open,

  -- Ports related to /dev/xillybus_read_8
  -- FPGA to CPU signals:
  user_r_read_8_rden => user_r_read_8_rden,
  user_r_read_8_empty => user_r_read_8_empty,
  user_r_read_8_data => user_r_read_8_data,
  user_r_read_8_eof => user_r_read_8_eof,
  user_r_read_8_open => user_r_read_8_open,

  -- Ports related to /dev/xillybus_write_32
  -- CPU to FPGA signals:
  user_w_write_32_wren => user_w_write_32_wren,
  user_w_write_32_full => user_w_write_32_full,
  user_w_write_32_data => user_w_write_32_data,
  user_w_write_32_open => user_w_write_32_open,

  -- Ports related to /dev/xillybus_write_8
  -- CPU to FPGA signals:
  user_w_write_8_wren => user_w_write_8_wren,
  user_w_write_8_full => user_w_write_8_full,
  user_w_write_8_data => user_w_write_8_data,
  user_w_write_8_open => user_w_write_8_open,

  -- General signals
  PCIE_PERST_B_LS => PCIE_PERST_B_LS,
  PCIE_REFCLK_N => PCIE_REFCLK_N,
  PCIE_REFCLK_P => PCIE_REFCLK_P,
  PCIE_RX_N => PCIE_RX_N,
  PCIE_RX_P => PCIE_RX_P,
  GPIO_LED => GPIO_LED,
  PCIE_TX_N => PCIE_TX_N,
  PCIE_TX_P => PCIE_TX_P,
  bus_clk => bus_clk,
  quiesce => quiesce
  );

--  A simple inferred RAM

  ram_addr <= conv_integer(user_mem_8_addr);

  process (bus_clk)

        begin 
            if (bus_clk'event and bus_clk = '1') then 

                wr_en <= user_w_write_8_wren;
                full <= user_w_write_8_full;                    
                if (user_w_write_8_wren='1' and counter = 0) then
                    my_buffer_a <= user_w_write_8_data;
                    counter <= 1;
                elsif (user_w_write_8_wren='1' and counter = 1) then
                    my_buffer_b <= user_w_write_8_data;
                    counter <= 2;
                elsif (counter = 2) then
                    full <= '1';
                    din <= my_buffer_a;
                    counter <= 3;
                elsif (counter = 3) then
                    full <= '1';
                    din <= my_buffer_b;
                    counter <= 0;
                end if;
            end if;

     end process;

  user_r_mem_8_empty <= '0';
  user_r_mem_8_eof <= '0';
  user_w_mem_8_full <= '0';

--  32-bit loopback

  fifo_32 : fifo_32x512
port map(
  clk        => bus_clk,
  srst       => reset_32,
  din        => user_w_write_32_data,
  wr_en      => user_w_write_32_wren,
  rd_en      => user_r_read_32_rden,
  dout       => user_r_read_32_data,
  full       => user_w_write_32_full,
  empty      => user_r_read_32_empty
  );

  reset_32 <= not (user_w_write_32_open or user_r_read_32_open);

  user_r_read_32_eof <= '0';

--  8-bit loopback

  fifo_8 : fifo_8x2048
  port map(
  clk        => bus_clk,
  srst       => reset_8,
  din        => din,
  wr_en      => wr_en,
  rd_en      => user_r_read_8_rden,
  dout       => user_r_read_8_data,
  full       => full,
  empty      => user_r_read_8_empty
  );

reset_8 <= not (user_w_write_8_open or user_r_read_8_open);

user_r_read_8_eof <= '0';

end sample_arch;
```

EDIT: Now, counter and buffers are signals instead of variables, so I'm sure they'll be sampled on the next clock cycle. Here, I would like to put some comments about my logic because I do not understand why it does not work.

```
begin 
if (bus_clk'event and bus_clk = '1') then 
   wr_en <= user_w_write_8_wren; --initialize wr_en
   full <= user_w_write_8_full;  --initialize full                  
   if (user_w_write_8_wren='1' and counter = 0) then --there data on write device file
       my_buffer_a <= user_w_write_8_data; --move the input data on buffer_a
       counter <= 1;
   elsif (user_w_write_8_wren='1' and counter = 1) then --there data on write device file
       my_buffer_b <= user_w_write_8_data; --move the input data on buffer_b
       counter <= 2;
   elsif (counter = 2) then
       full <= '1'; --do not accept more data
       din <= my_buffer_a; --take data stored in buffer_a and move it into read_device_file
       counter <= 3;
   elsif (counter = 3) then
       full <= '1'; --do not accept more data
       din <= my_buffer_b; --take data stored in buffer_b and move it into read_device_file
       counter <= 0;
   end if;
end if;
end process;
```

1-Why should I have to initialize `rd_en` and `empty`? Well, I don't understand where I have to use them in my logic. I think I do not need information about read_device_file such as no more data can be read or there is valid data on read_device_file.

2-Why does `wr_en` contain the old value of `user_w_write_8_wren`? Since I do `wr_en <= user_w_write_8_wren;`, `wr_en` should contain the actual value of `user_w_write_8_wren`, isn't it?

Comment: Please note,  that the code in the question you have linked is broken. Please read the documentation on XillyBus and start a new Implementation.

Comment: With this code I am able to generate the bitfile. I read the documentation and what I have got is that I have to play with `user_w_write_8_data` to get data from write device file and put it into FIFO and with `user_r_mem_8_data` to take data from FIFO and put it into read device file. I do all checks when the clock is 1. I don't understand why it does not work. Can you tell me where is broken?

Comment: You have to respect all the other control signals like `rden` , `wren` , `full` and `empty` of the XillyBus as well.

Comment: Now we have a better look. Please note that you rely on the old values of `wr_en` in  the `if(wr_en` conditions. Is this really intended or do you want to check the actual value of `user_w_write_8_wren`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1-Why should I have to initialize rd_en and empty?

You have **not** to "initialize" this signals. Just connect them properly to the XillyBus.

The output `empty` of the FIFO indicates whether data is available in the FIFO. If it's low, then more data can be read from the FIFO. This output should be connected to the signal `user_r_read_8_empty` which is connected to the same-named input of the XillyBus.

The input `rd_en` of the FIFO should be connected to the signal `user_r_read_8_rden` which is connected to the same-named output of the XillyBus. This signal is driven high by the XillyBus, if it wants to read data from the FIFO.

For you intended design, you have to replace the FIFO as described at the end of this answer.

> 2-Why does wr_en contain the old value of user_w_write_8_wren?

Because signal assigments in a process (with operator `<=`) are delayed until the next `wait` statement. Only variable assigments (with operator `:=`) have an immediate effect.

Your `process(bus_clk)` does not have an explicit `wait` statement. But, it has an implicit one, because a process with a sensitivity list (the `(bus_clock)`) is equal to a process without a sensitivity list with a `wait on` statement at the end. Thus, your code equals:

```
process
begin 
    if (bus_clk'event and bus_clk = '1') then 
        wr_en <= user_w_write_8_wren;
        full <= user_w_write_8_full;                    
        if (user_w_write_8_wren='1' and counter = 0) then
        ...
        end if;
    end if;
    wait on bus_clock;
end process;
```

The signal assignments to `wr_en` and `full` (as well as all other signal assigments in this process) are applied at the end of the process. Thus, if you would check the value of `wr_en` in the `if` conditions, always the still valid old value would be used.

For example, in hardware the signal `wr_en` would be implemented with a D flip-flop which is triggered by the rising edge of `bus_clk` here. The signal `wr_en` would be the output of the D flip-flop and the expression on the right side of the signal assignment (`user_w_write_8_wren`) the input of this D flip-flop. Thus, `wr_en` is `user_w_write_8_wren` delayed by one clock cycle in this example.

**How you should proceed:**

I recommend to restart from the XillyBus loopback demo (xillydemo). Then you should encapsulate your own logic into a separaty entity which **replaces** the FIFO `fifo_8`. More on this topic, I have written in [an answer to the other question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/206846/91366).